# My modules don't seem to be setup in IntelliJ correctly when pulling from source

Tags: java, spring, git, intellij-idea

On a new computer, I pulled from source my intellij project (spring mvc), and when it opened up I got 10+ errors having to do with the maven modules not being setup correctly etc.

I noticed my appname.iml wasn't in m git repository.

I have this in my .gitignore:

*.iml

Should this file be included, or only this single appname.iml is required?

Answer (score 1):

If you don't share `.iml` files, you also don't need to share `.idea` directory. In this case you will need to open `pom.xml` or use the new project wizard to import from Maven. Settings that are stored in IntelliJ IDEA project will have to be configured again on every machine.

If you choose to share IntelliJ IDEA project files (`.idea` directory and `.iml`), [refer to the FAQ](http://devnet.jetbrains.net/docs/DOC-1186).